# Image not moving when window resizing

Tags: cocoa, resize

I have a window mostly filled with an image view. When I resize the window from the top right, the image stays where it is, and the window covers and uncovers the image as I move the mouse around. However, when I resize from the bottom left, instead of the window covering up that corner, the image moves with the window's corner.

How do I get the image to remain where it is, no matter which side I'm resizing the window from?

p.s. this is using Cocoa

Comment: Do you want the image view to resize with the window or not?

Comment: I want the image to not resize, since I have separate functions for zooming, I simply want the window to resize independent to the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change **Autosizing** property of `NSImageView`. It can be done by selecting imageView and going to **Size Inspector** and then changing **Autosizing**.

Or all this can be done programatically like this:

```
// Example shows how to turn all autosizing params to imageView

[imageViewOutlet setAutoresizingMask: NSViewMinXMargin | NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin | NSViewHeightSizable | NSViewMaxYMargin];
```

Comment: I tried all the different combinations of Autosizing. Although I can stop it from getting bigger, I can't stop the origin of the image from moving with the window..

Comment: @Mirror318 If you want that your imageView can't become bigger use this: `[imageViewOutlet setAutoresizingMask: NSViewNotSizable];`.

Comment: I already have it not resizing, but I want it to not move with the window when the window is resized.

Comment: @Mirror318 then I think You need to change imageView's origins depending on window resizing size. You can make it not moving with one side but not both.  So I can think of is to change imageView's origin depending on resizing windows size to stay in same possition. (Window is bigger or smaller so imageView's origin can't be the same..)